# MongoDB query collection A with response of collection B

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to query the collection `entityType` and then check the collection `status` for the entities valid status Id's. I'm not trying to do this in nodejs / any backend, but directly on the database.

What I thought should work:

```
var foo = db.entitytype.find({name: 'user'}).map((e) => e._id)
db.status.find({entityType: foo});
```

foo is:

[image: query of entityType collection]

I also tried an async approach like this:

```
db.entitytype.find({name: 'user'}, (err, entityType) => {
  if (err) return;
  db.status.find({entityType: entityType._id})
});
```

But this only queries the `entityType` collection, not the `status` collection.

Not that it should matter, but I'm using mongobooster for the query. I also tried ES5 code, but the result is the same.

How can this be done in mongodb?

Comment: [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) or [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

Comment: thank you! `$in` works, which seems to me a bit odd, since I'm querying `status` with a single entry (and querying with `{entityType: ObjectId('herebeid')}` directly works?

Comment: So just call [`.toArray()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Cursor.html#toArray). The `.find()` by itself is a "cursor", but `.toArray()` pulls all contents as an "array". So then you can just [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) ( which is a regular JavaScript method for arrays ) each `_id` value to pass to `$in`.

Comment: I tried `toArray()` before, but I don't get a result. The solution with `$in` works though. it`s a little bit strange in my opinion, but whatever, problem solved I guess